# Visual c# applications sending string message from sender to receiver, using Sendmessage()

Tags: c#, winforms, sendmessage

I am developing two windows apps, sender and receiver, in C#. In the sender, I want to have a text box for keying in the string message, and button "send".

On the other hand, I want to have a windows app receiver, receiving the string message in a textbox.

I couldn't find any step-by-step tutorial specifically on app to app, although have found quite feel on app to notepad... I have no idea how to convert those to-notepad code to to-window-app-textbox one.....

Here is what I found about app to notepad:

http://www.codingvision.net/miscellaneous/c-send-text-to-notepad

Comment: Using SendMessage() to do this is a fairly bad idea, discovering the window handle is tricky and the string has to be marshaled across the process boundary.  Technically you can do it with WM_COPYDATA.  But do consider the .NET interop mechanisms first.  A socket, named pipe or WCF.

Comment: Are there any examples/tutorials of this kind? Thanks!

Comment: @Curly Yes, [490000 of them](https://www.google.com/search?q=wcf+tutorial+c%23)

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I am asking for though....

Answer (score 0):

You could look into a Memory Mapped File between your applications. You need to decide on a messaging system/protocol and send the messages through a shared memory tunnel(s) between you app and others as needed.

Also, look at what SignalR is doing. It is placing the messaging on the transport layer.